# Subject and verb of the sentence?

Tags: verbs, subjects

> It is unacceptable to submit an essay from a previous course.

I am having a hard time finding the verb and the subject of this sentence. I searched online. From what I understood the answer should be "essay" "submit" but not sure.

Comment: Syntactically, the primary subject is the pronoun ***it***, and the primary verb is ***is***. Semantically, ***it*** refers to (stands in for) the "compound verb" sequence *to submit an essay from a previous course*, which could be converted to a noun form as ***Submitting** an essay from a previous course [is unacceptable].*

Comment: It's an extraposition construction where the subject is the meaningless dummy pronoun "it" and the matrix ('main') verb is "is". The extraposed subject has the verb "submit".

Comment: @BillJ  thanks, I couldn't remember what this use of "it" was called.

Comment: What if the sentence was "Another way to think of it is as animals." What would the verb and subject be? Im trying to understand but complex sorry

Comment: @BillJ: Are you sure about that? In ***It's raining*** (a traditional example of "dummy it") it's not easy say what ***it*** refers to, but with OP's example it's obvious that the "referent" is actually present, and can work perfectly well without even including the "dummy": *To submit an essay from a previous course is unacceptable.*

Comment: The subject is "another way to think of it", and the main verb is "is". Note that the subject itself contains the subordinate clause "to think of it", where the verb is "think"

Comment: In Extraposition the "it" is a dummy element, serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position; the extraposed element doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of "it" but serves simply as a semantic argument of the VP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Is"** is the main verb of the sentence.  **"It"** is the subject.

This is an example of the common ["dummy pronoun"](http://www.brighthubeducation.com/english-homework-help/60131-existential-there-and-dummy-it-pronouns/) structure in English.  "It" has no meaning, and is just used as a kind of *placeholder* in the sentence.

> **It is** good to eat breakfast every morning.
>
> **It is** smart to check your sources before submitting an answer
>
> **It is** a bad idea to stick your hand in the lion's cage.
>
> **It is** unacceptable to forget my birthday.

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if the sentence was "Another way to think of it is as animals." What would the verb and subject be? Im trying to understand but complex sorry.

Comment: @Harout 'Another way to think of it' is the subject. This has been answered by BillJ in the comment under your post.